# php and mysqli code wont enter data into my data base

Tags: php, mysqli

Database name: `forumTutorial`
table name: `threads`

```
4 Columns:  
id      - INT     - 5    Length - Primary Key - Auto Increment (AI/A_I).  
title   - VARCHAR - 255  Length
content - VARCHAR - 2000 Length  
author  - VARCHAR - 255  Length
```

I didnt get any errors.. it just says failed to create

```
<?php
session_start();
//$_SESSION['username'] = 'Admin';
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'forumTutorial') or die(mysql_error());
if (isSet($_POST['createThread'])) {
    if (isSet($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] != '' && isSet($_POST['content']) && $_POST['content'] != '' && isSet($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '') {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        $q = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `threads` VALUES ('', '$title', '$content', '$user')");
        if ($q) {
            echo 'Thread created.';
        }else
            echo 'Failed to create thread.';
    }
}?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Create Thread:</h1>
    <form action='forumTutorial.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Title: </td><td><input type='text' name='title' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description: </td><td><input type='text' name='content' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><input type='submit' value='Create Thread' name='createThread' /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to add error handling so that you see what is wrong. You could be sql injecting yourself; you should switch to prepared statements.

Comment: php is case sensitive isSet is not a function use "isset()" and your query is is susceptible to SQL injection

Comment: PHP is NOT case sensitive, where did you get that... only variables are case sensitive in php, function names, class names, and even namespaces are not case sensitive except in their autoloading constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the fields in your insert query. Also, since your id field is set to AUTO_INCREMENT, you shouldn't send any value. Change this:

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `threads` VALUES ('', '$title', '$content', '$user')");
```

To this:

```
$q = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `threads` (title, content, author) VALUES ('$title', '$content', '$user')");
```